# Use of "were" and "would" in past tense

Tags: sentence-construction, past-continuous

I want to say to my school friend that:

> This is the same bench on which we would seat in our school days.

Or should is say,

> This is the same bench on which we were sitting in our school days.

Comment: This is the same bench we used to sit on when we were in school.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with, "This is the same bench on which we would **sit** in our school days," as I find it a little less awkward. I don't know that your second alternative is unacceptable though...

P.S. I think these are technically "[past real conditional](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/pastconditional.html)" and "[past continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html)," respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the same bench on which we would **seat** in our school day - Incorrect.

Prefer telling -

> This is the same bench **we would sit** on in our school days.

The verb *would* is preferred when the action in past happened regularly.

[WordWeb defines it:](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=would)

> **Would** (v): *Indicating an action in the past that happened repeatedly or commonly.*

On the other hand, *"This is the same bench on which we were sitting in our school days"* is also correct but it would indicate one particular point of time and not a regular event.

See this -

> *Yes, I proposed her here; this is the same bench we were sitting on.*